# Sticky navbar script has stopped working

Tags: javascript, html, css, navbar

I've tried to get my navbar to stick when I scroll, but it just isn't working...
Maybe one of you knows a way to fix it...

**My HTML:**
[image: HTML snippet]

**Associated JavaScript:**
[image: JavaScript code]

**Associated CSS:**
[image: CSS code]

**EDIT**
Ok I found out that the problem is in this script, just have to find out what it is.
[image: Error spotted]

Comment: What do you mean by "it isn't working"? What happens that is different to the expected behaviour?

Comment: Well, the navbar isn't sticking when I'm scrolling but it was before and i cant find what changed. so I think it is the javascript but I'm not sure.

Comment: Moved images into the question body. As a rule of thumb, put code as text  instead of images into the question body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure your JavaScript is at the bottom of the page as it won't fire if the page hasn't loaded yet or better still ensure it is triggered after the page is loaded using an `onload` event like so:

```
<body onload="myFunction()">
```

Comment: It is in a javascript file in the <head>.